# Problem in Spring dynamic web project without maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, sessionfactory

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sci'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'di'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'daoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sf'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Aug 29, 2023 9:44:19 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sci'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'di'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'daoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sf'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I want to save our data in database through spring mvc

Comment: Use maven or gradle to manage the needed dependencies. Don't go looking around for dependencies yourself, you will end up with a mix that kind of works but not really. Use the proper tools.

Comment: What do you mean "without maven"? :D Thats just insane, I work since 300 years in java and I know noone ever tried without maven.

Comment: You provide too little information, without knowing how your project is structured, how you are building and running it etc. it's impossible to tell from just the error message what is wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.